# Is it even possible to hack a television channel?

Tags: network, wireless

In spite of all the hacking news in the recent few years I never heard of someone who managed to hack a TV channel. What makes them so secure?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet would be to target the personal workstations of the editors, subtly modify their work and hope nobody catches it before it goes on-air.

Comment: I would've thought [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2efhrCxI4J0) would be a better clip to pick :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure they did it on Mission Impossible once.

Comment: @Polynomial Wow! That was amazing, [from 2:40 to EOF!](http://youtu.be/2efhrCxI4J0?t=2m40s) Thank you. I'd never seen it before.

Comment: @Polynomial "unbelievable... a hacker".

Comment: If I recall correctly in that film (V for vendetta) he was physically on the premises and basically forced the operaters to upload this. I wouldn't call this "hacking" in the traditional sense

Comment: @EllieKesselman It's from the movie "Hackers", which everyone should definitely see. Cheesy as hell, soundtrack by The Prodigy, stars Angelina Jolie from when she was practically a kid.

Comment: If you're from Chicago and over forty, you should remember this hilariously weird incident: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Headroom_broadcast_signal_intrusion

Comment: I'm not completely sure if this is a fake, but this is a relatively recent example of a TV station being hacked: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/03/01/colbert-anonymous-hacked-_n_829604.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hacking a television station is *hard*.  Most of the broadcast infrastructure isn't connected to the Internet, making outside intrusion difficult or impossible.

Let's say you want to hack your local news station.  Problem #1 is that their equipment isn't connected to the Internet -- it's quite possible that they're still using a bank of Betamax machines for ads and canned programs, and direct-wired connections for live television.  Problem #2 is that the broadcast antenna has either a hard-wired connection to the studio or a narrow-beam microwave connection.  Taking over their broadcast pretty much requires a physical break-in.

Okay, how about taking over a satellite broadcast?  These days, those are usually encrypted to prevent unauthorized people from listening in, so you can't replace the official uplink with your own, even if you can get a powerful enough transmitter into a location that the satellite is listening to.

The most common form of "hacking" is [pirate television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_television), where someone sets up an unauthorized transmitter and broadcasts, possibly overwhelming the signal from an authorized user of the channel.  That said, other forms of hacking [do occasionally occur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_signal_intrusion).

Comment: What about re-broadcasters and people running HFC networks offering N-in-1 services, where one of the services is television? Such systems are in fact often either connected to Internet or are a part of same infrastructure used to provide Internet access

Comment: Probably the most famous case of broadcast signal intrusion is the [Max Headroom incidents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Headroom_broadcast_signal_intrusion) in Chicago in 1987.

Comment: @AndrejaKo TV and cable internet (DOCSIS) can use the same medium simultaneously (for example, I could connect my cable modem and a DVB-T TV tuner to the antenna outlet and they both worked) but that doesn't mean they use the same infrastructure, they just happen to use the same physical wire.

Comment: @André Daniel Are you quite sure about that? Most cable systems use optical fibers as far as they can before switching to coaxial cables. I could be wrong, but I was under very strong impression that the TV signal is streamed through the fiber up to the demarcation point between the fiber and coaxial cable (can't remember the technical word right now), where the emission of the TV signal through the coaxial cable starts.

Comment: @André Daniel Furthermore, IPTV systems pushed by some DSL (and fiber to the home) providers basically use multicast for the signal and the TV is actually sharing the same path as the Internet, leaving room for hacking what are basically computer systems and this is where the big part of the "too different to hack" defense fails. Also as a side-note what would be your definition of infrastructure if sharing the same wire isn't sharing the infrastructure?

Comment: @AndrejaKo yeah, the TV signal goes through the same fiber, but then is converted to DVB-T before going into the coaxial cable. I said the infrastructure was different because DVB-T is one-way (as far as I know), so even though they use the same wire there's no way to "talk" to the DVB-T transmitter in order to exploit it.

Comment: @AndrejaKo yeah, in cases where the TV goes though IP there is a possibility to talk to the server that streams the TV channels and exploit it, that depends on the ISP though, most of them either use security through obscurity, IPSec (so that only their authorized decoder box can receive the TV channels) and the IPTV server is often only reachable through a separate ATM VC (in case of DSL).

Comment: @André Daniel I'm not talking about hacking the DVB signal itself (which should be DVB-C for cable), I'm talking about substituting the signal on its way to the DVB modulator. As far as I know, it's often sent using IP, which leaves room for it to be attacked.

Comment: @André Daniel I fully agree with your latest comment.

Comment: @AndrejaKo but in order to talk to the DVB modulator you'd need physical access or compromise the infrastructure that the ISP uses to manage them, they're not reachable from the Internet nor from the network used by the DOCSIS modems to deliver Internet access.

Comment: @AndrejaKo that is of course pure speculation, I have little experience with this and there's very little documentation about how all that DOCSIS cable internet works, let alone IPTV (in which there seems to be no standard, each ISP rolls their own proprietary protocol).

Comment: "a bank of Betamax machines"? seriously? that's like some ancient alien technology

Comment: This hasn't been active since 2015, but I'm wondering - what's the difference now? We have different ways of watching television now, with more methods of watching being over the internet, especially with Sky Stream and IPTV.

Comment: @Permanently, these days, hacking is probably much easier.  The Betamax machines and physical-media distribution are mostly gone, replaced by Internet distribution.  This gives you an access point that doesn't require breaking and entering.