# How can hackers do a tv signal intrusion?

Tags: network, wireless

How can hackers do incidents like the [Max Headroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Headroom_broadcast_signal_intrusion) one?

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71635/is-it-even-possible-to-hack-a-television-channel) is related, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for how a hacker can do any sort of tv signal intrusion or are you looking for how they did that specific intrusion? AFAIK they still don't know how the Max Headroom incident was done.

Comment: I am looking for how a hacker can do any sort of tv signal intrusion. The Max Headroom incident is just an exmaple.

Comment: You mean broadcast TV? If so, I'm not sure that's an Information Security question. If not, then it is way too broad.

Comment: @schroeder Intruding on analog signals is certainly related to information security. I mean if lock picking is on-topic, surely analog transmissions are?

Comment: You could post a summary on your question, along with the links. Links can die, and your question would not make sense...

Comment: afaik, that used an amateur microwave transmitter aimed precisely at WGN's retransmittion microwave transceiver that was able to over-power the remote signal with a closer-source signal. Everything is digital now, and likely signed, so that exploit won't work anymore.

Comment: I don't think its signed so much as being transmitted to satellites that require great precision to communicate with and a lot of domain-specific expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute your own TV signal at various levels, which would differ in affected range and would require different hardware.

1. range: **global**, broadcaster detection and avoidance: **very fast**, cost: **moderate**: impersonate transmission car. You need:

   - satellite transmission hardware just like the car equipment,
   - uplink parameters: frequency, modulation, symbol rate and BISS key. They can be sniffed easily from some ongoing transmission.

You can go online during some event, but you'll shortly be put down by "please excuse us, we have some technical problems out there".

2. range: **large**, broadcaster detection and avoidance: **hours**, cost: **very large**: impersonate signal origin (transmission site). Depending on area you want to cover, you must either put your signal into satellite or fiber feed. In case of fiber you need to know the location, probably at some patchpanel (messing in the ground would alert many people very fast), for sat you'll have to know the transmission scheme and disable the original transmitter. This is mostly movie or war-scenario, I can't imagine performing such attack without using force or very much money - 4 m diameter antenna weights about 250 kg and costs about 10k$, you might need to use 7 m antenna... But using your force you could take over the origin site itself and make them transmit your signal.

   2a. the easier to perform might be possible if there is an unprotected feed from the studio to the transmit site. You'll need some insider knowledge, as the link is private by design (no well-known satellites, no easy-spottable huge antennas and transmit towers, no well-known broadcasting stations).
3. range: **regional**, broadcaster detection and avoidance: **hours-day or two**, cost: **large**: impersonate signal origin at some receiving site. In this scenario you put your signal into some regional redistribution point, like DVB-T transmitter or IP eXchange point. Much cheaper than previous variant, but similar. Receivers have less staff doing maintenance, the receiving party would not block you (previously this was some IXP or sat operator, now this is the redistribution site itself), you just need to climb to their antennas or fiber with your cable, you can gather all the required knowledge from single person working at the site.
4. range: **local**, broadcaster detection and avoidance: **day or a few**, cost: **relatively small**: put your signal directly into viewers at some area. You can either tap into CATV operator fiber infrastructure:

   - locate any fiber,
   - receive and filter-out 1550 nm wave, pass 1310/1490 bands,
   - demodulate DVB (this would be something between 20 and 40 DVB-C channels), decode MPEG-TS of your choice, change anything you want, modulate again,
   - transmit your signal into the fiber in 1550 band.

This is very easy for (G)EPON networks, but if the CATV operator uses DOCSIS for n-play, you'll have to deal with providing IP services in order to be not detected soon.

Or provide stronger radio signal than the one in the area and made the receivers tune to yours. In this case you'll need only the DVB-T head-end (about 1k$ per channel), an amplifier and antenna (depending on the area you want to cover).

Answer (score 0):

The antenna has an input, amplifier, and an output (antenna). So, you change the input signal.

Maybe the input runs over a T1, ISDN, Frame Relay, fiber, or a coaxial cable. It changes depending on the era. I'm not a transmission history buff, but the concept is the same. Break the cable and feed your data into the input.

With RF, the signal is modulated. If you can pump a stronger competing signal, the receivers may lock in to the strongest signal and demodulate it. That's why your FM radio used to pickup one or the other radio station, but not both at the same time (unless it was AM).